# Fetching new instagram medias from a realtime update

Tags: real-time, instagram, real-time-updates

I don't think that is a bug but rather an issue for me, lemme explain...

I have a subscription to the realtime updates for a particular tag.

When [receiving the POST request](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/#receiving-updates) from instagram (notifying new medias have arrived), I get the following:

```
[
  {
    changed_aspect: 'media',
    object: 'tag',
    object_id: 'nofilter',
    time: 1401648280,
    subscription_id: 5165151,
    data: {}
  }
]
```

Then, in order to fetch the corresponding new content, I fetch recent medias and filter them by comparing their `created_time` to the subscription's time, ie: `media.created_time >= 1401648280`

Unfortunately, sometimes, the `media.created_time` is 1ms behind: `1401648279` ... So that media isn't return in my filtered list of "new" medias.

--

I understand why subscription's time can be later and I can give a tolerance for my filter comparison: `time - media.created_time <= X` but I don't know how to set `X`: 10ms ? 100ms? 2s?

Do you know that value? A guaranteed amount of time within the subscription will be generated after new media updates?

Thank you in advance and best regards